# PHP or JS GET form: How to add a field if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, checkbox

I have basic html form with several checkbox fields. I want to add another field if a checkbox is checked so the added field is passed via url. My code so far, but it is not working:

```
<form action="/s/mypage/" method="GET">
<input name="id1" type="checkbox" value="ime" checked/>Input 1
<input name="id11" type="checkbox" value="deinost" />Input 11
<input name="id2" type="checkbox" value="adres" />Input 2
<input name="id3" type="checkbox" value="kapital" />Input 3
<input name="id4" type="checkbox" value="upravitel" />Input 4
<input name="id5" type="checkbox" value="sobstvenik" />Input 5
<input name="id6" type="checkbox" value="drugo" />Input 6
<input name="" type="submit" value="go ahead" />

<?php
if (isset($_GET["id[1]"])) {
echo '<input type="hidden" name="do" value="12345" />';
}
?>
</form>
```

How can i do that? It is not neccessary to be with php, javascript will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the condition depends on the checkbox state, you probably want to do this in javascript on the client-side. One approach is so do a check when the form is being submitted. If you use jQuery, it could look something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  if($('#id1').is(':checked')) {
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="do" value="12345" />');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Why isn't this && operator not working? 

if($('#id1').is(':checked') && $('#id2').is(':checked')) {
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="do" value="12345" />');
  }

Comment: The syntax looks right. I'd suggest you try to `console.log($('#id1').is(':checked') && $('#id2').is(':checked'))` and see if that returns true. If it does then you know the condition is being met. Otherwise, check each element individually to try and narrow down issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
<script>
   $(function(){
       $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
         if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
            /// your code goes here if a checkbox checked
          }
       })
   }) 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<td>
<input type ="checkbox" id ="morning"> Morning</td><td class="hiden css"> After which period want break  </td>
                                    <td> <input type="text" class="hiden css" id="morning_break" pattern ="[0-9]+" name="morning_break"></td>
                  </table>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".hiden,.hide1").hide();
        });
   $("#morning").click(function(){
        $(".hiden").toggle();
    });
```

> Here the code works well on your requirement